# Tooltip position issue in css jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

I want to display tooltip on the upper side of my text.

If you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EWwRs/ , on mouse move it comes below the link and disturb my design.

I want it to display at the upper section and should not disturb my existing design but should show as tooltip or title.

Here is some code

```
$(".currency").mouseover(function(){
//tooltip();
 $('#tooltip-' + this.id).show({
    effect: 'slide'
});
});
```

For more details see above fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Add `position: absolute` to `.tooltip`

Then use margin to position the div, there where you want it...

Comment: it is dynamic created in a loop...every tooltip has different position..how i can do?can you use my fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/EWwRs/4/

You can also combine `mouseover` and `mouseout` scripts,

## JQUERY

```
var delay = 400;
$(".currency").mouseover(function(){
    $('#tooltip-' + this.id).show({
        effect: 'slide'
    });
}).mouseout(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$('#tooltip-' + this.id).hasClass('hovering')){
            $('#tooltip-' + this.id).hide();
        }
    }, delay)
});

$('.tooltip').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hovering');
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('hovering');
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$('.tooltip').hasClass('hovering')){
            $('.tooltip').hide();
        }
    }, delay)
});
```

## CSS

```
.tooltip {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-210px;    
    margin-left:0;
    z-index:10;
    background:green url(/images/black_arrow.png);
    height:103px;
    padding:25px;
    width:196px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font:11px/11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border:3px solid red;
}
```